# How to secure RedisInsight?

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kong, redisinsights

I have a RedisInsight instance running in my Kubernetes cluster. I exposed it using Kong Ingress. My issue is that when I display it it doesn´t have any mechanismn of authentication.

I already set the environemnt variables: RITRUSTEDORIGINS, RIAUTHPROMPT, RIAUTHTIMER. But this doesn´t give the level of security that I want. With this in place anyone can access my site and delete any databases without the need of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

**Redis** **insight** maybe not provide any type of **Auth** option. **Redis** provides the **auth** and **TLS** options generally.

So if you are using the **Kong** gateway you can set use the **plugin** with Kong to setup the Auth on the URL of insight. There is tons of option available with Kong for **Auth** like **API key**, **JWT**, **User/Pass** etc.

Answer (score 0):

we have sample setups of multiple levels of proxy authentications.

If you want to add admin level password to protect from redisinsight v1, check this out - https://github.com/RedisInsight/RedisInsight-reverse-proxy

The variables you have mentioned don't protect RedisInsight itself but the protection is at the instance level. It doesn't allow a user to access an instance for which they don't have a password even if the instance is added to RedisInsight. Here's the description of RedisInsight v1 environment variables you have mentioned:

- `RITRUSTEDORIGINS` - This makes RI reachable via the domain you are hosting.
- `RIAUTHPROMPT` - This makes the authentication prompt available. The username and password are the same as the one for that redis the prompt is shown.
- `RIAUTHTIMER` - How often the prompt to be shown.